# Storing and Finding Art Assets

Tags: art, asset-management

I've started down a line of art asset development that will allow me to (hopefully) reuse and improve assets for several games.

But how do I go about storing and finding them?

Let's say for example I decide to focus on RPGs for ~2 years. I would create items, monsters, etc. and store them somewhere. How would I categorize them and make them easier to search later on?

Is the best solution "use directories with broad categories like landscape/items/monsters/etc.?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a Wordpress installation for it. It has an image gallery, and allows you to upload images and tag/categorize them (if you use one image per post).

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using directories with broad categories?

You can just put more specific categories if you find that you really have too many assets within a directory.

You could just organize it this way:

`ArtAssets`

which contains:

`Landscape` -> (only if you have a lot of landscapes) `Forest`, `City`, `Sky`, etc.

`Items` -> `Weapons`, `Armors`, `Potions`, `Miscellaneous`, etc.

`Characters` -> `Enemies`, `Players`, `NPCs`, etc.

I'd say start out with very broad categories and if you find yourself having to search a lot through a category to find an asset, get more specific categories.

Comment: The main problem with that is that the directory lends itself to only one kind of organization.  Ideally there would be a way to "tag" assets so you can, say, search for anything that's "blue", or "moody" and get stuff across those categories.

Comment: @Tetrad: Oh well, maybe that's because I'm used to having not so much art assets with my games. I never thought such intensive categorization would be required. My bad, I guess there is a program somewhere that can handle that.

Comment: This doesn't really scale well. It's really hard to find stuff, even if you know that you have an image of X.

Answer (score 1):

[Alienbrain asset manager](http://alienbrain.com/) is a good start.

Comment: Pretty pricey. Plus, I want this for 2d assets, not even textures for 3d assets.